# Rescue fstab, invalid argument mounting my disk ext4

Tags: freebsd, mount, fstab

I have a problem, I think I wrong to edit /etc/fstab on centos7 and I cannot reboot my remote server.

I'm in rescue mode with freebsd.

I cannot mount my ada0s3 (on centos was sda3) to fix my fstab.

```
root@rescuefbsd:/mnt # gpart show -p ada0
=>        63  3907029105    ada0  MBR  (1.8T)
          63        1985          - free -  (993K)
        2048        2048  ada0s1  linux-data  (1.0M)
        4096     1024000  ada0s2  linux-data  [active]  (500M)
     1028096  3889223680  ada0s3  linux-data  (1.8T)
  3890251776    16777216  ada0s4  ebr  (8.0G)
  3907028992         176          - free -  (88K)



root@rescuefbsd:/mnt # file -s /dev/ada0s3 
/dev/ada0s3: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=80281fb1-7589-4a01-b2d0-6e6529e6b09b (needs journal recovery) (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)

root@rescuefbsd:/mnt # dmesg | grep ada0
ada0 at ahcich0 bus 0 scbus0 target 0 lun 0
ada0: <WDC WD2002FAEX-007BA0 05.01D05> ATA-8 SATA 3.x device
ada0: Serial Number WD-WMAY02628053
ada0: 300.000MB/s transfers (SATA 2.x, UDMA6, PIO 8192bytes)
ada0: Command Queueing enabled
ada0: 1907729MB (3907029168 512 byte sectors: 16H 63S/T 16383C)
ada0: Previously was known as ad4
WARNING: mount of ada0s3 denied due to unsupported optional features
WARNING: mount of ada0s3 denied due to unsupported optional features
WARNING: mount of ada0s3 denied due to unsupported optional features
WARNING: mount of ada0s3 denied due to unsupported optional features
```

Tried (some solution on google):

```
root@rescuefbsd:/mnt # mount -t ext4 /dev/ada0s3 /mnt
mount: /dev/ada0s3: Operation not supported by device

root@rescuefbsd:/mnt # mount /dev/ada0s3 /mnt
mount: /dev/ada0s3: Invalid argument

root@rescuefbsd:/mnt # mount -t ext2fs -o ro /dev/ada0s3 /mnt
mount: /dev/ada0s3: Invalid argument
```

Some idea please?

Comment: Most likely your FreeBSD rescue systeem simply does not support EXT4 filesystems, boot from a Linux rescue image instead...

Comment: I have only freebsd and my server is remote.I cannot take an airport to go in NL...

Comment: A quick search pointed to that FreeBSD is only able to mount ext4 in fuse mode. So you would have to load the driver `kldload fuse.ko`, then `ext4fuse /dev/ada0s3 /mnt`. Hoping all the necessary tools are provided on the rescue system.

Answer (score -1):

Solved, my hosting provide me Rescue 3.0 that support ext4.